# Parsing JSON from Google API on iPhone

Tags: iphone, json

**EDITED CODE**

I had done in this way:

```
// Create new SBJSON parser object
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    // Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&sll=23.00,72.00&radius=2000&output=json"]];

    // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [json_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"while(1);" withString:@""];

    NSDictionary *json_dict = [json_string JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",json_dict);
```

But then also I'm getting `null` in `json_dict`

I want to parse the data which I get from Google Webservice.

http://www.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&sll=23.00,72.00&radius=2000&output=json

I have used the below code:

```
// Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request for Getting the Restaurent at particular coordinate.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&sll=23.00,72.00&radius=2000&output=json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// parse the JSON response into an object
// Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

But I am not getting the response. If I use some other API like: http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json, it will parse properly, but this does not work for Google APIs

I had checked the response string in JSON version. The response which we get is forming a proper tree. It is not showing any error but the array in response which I get is null.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:

I was looking into and found out that it is not a proper response as you get a file with JSON extension and not a JSON response as is the case with twitter api you are referring. So my advice refer [google places api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) and find a JSON response for a list of restaurants and then try again.

In order to hit there api key you need authenticate with your own api key which you get using [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication).

once you get your api key you can hit the api like this..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

this in return will give you a JSON response which you can parse easily (this returns a dictionary) and  voila you are done(this api is limited to 100 hits per day only.)... hoping this helps.

So your code will look like this and will work I have checked it...

```
/// Create new SBJSON parser object 
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    // Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=yourOwnAPIKey"]];

    // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // parse the JSON response into an object
    // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    NSLog(@"statuses:%@", statuses);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I had even tried to take Dictonary but the response i m getting is always null..

Comment: @Thanks Ankit..for the reply..I had created the google key and tried to get the data..But i got the Response as REQUEST_DENEID..The url whihc i had used is:-https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDLjucaGZ_1JJi2-UOsJ2YYbyu8-UXlHr0

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava this is not Twitter Api ,it looks like a Google Api..! take another view to that URL.

Comment: she says that it works with the twitter api which she has mentioned after the google api(read the 6th line from below and then re read my answer.)

Comment: please don't be using my key as it is registered under my name, it was just an example to show you... I am going to delete it.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava i dont know..But i had done in same way and appended the API KEY..But didnt get it

Comment: are you sure you enabled it for the place api in the authentication...? because that's what I have done and it is working for me.

Comment: @Ankit i had enable the access for place api authentication from services tab..it is the right way to enable the place api??

Comment: @shweta hey your key is working now.. try this it contains your key.. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDLjucaGZ_1JJi2-UOsJ2YYbyu8-UXlHr0

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava thanks my key is working now..But if i change the Latitude-longitude then it is not showing any response and giving me ZERO_RESULT.The url is :- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.8670522,72.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDLjucaGZ_1JJi2-UOsJ2YYbyu8-UXlHr0

Answer (score 2):

use this

> ```
> NSDictionary *json_dict = [responseString JSONValue];
> NSLog(@"%@",json_dict);
> ```

then you can fetch any value using its key

Comment: @Thanks for the reply i had done it that way..but still not getting reply.Had edited the question

Answer (score 1):

The response string from http://www.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&sll=23.00,72.00&radius=2000&output=json is started with `while(1);`, it is not a valid JSON, remove it should work.

Comment: @Thanks for the reply..I had done in that way and edited my question..Please check it and help me..

Answer (score 1):

you can use google places api by replacing url to this

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=2000&types=restaurant&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Generate your key from Google "https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:305239127220"

Comment: used this but got this error:-{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: have you replaced the key with you generated key, also tries to run the url on simply web browser and check what it return.

Comment: i had created the apikey and even changed the sensor parameter.And it is explained it in this url-http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/  But then also getting access denied

Comment: Have you enabled the Google places services from the Google console"https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:305239127220:services" check from this link

Comment: Its the error of your key which is not able to get access from Google server, I have tried the same link by changing your key to my key and its working fine. Try by deleting this key and generating your key. Hope this helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8533/discussion-between-shweta-and-challenger)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a URLRequest you can directly download the contents from the URL into your jsonString like this

```
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"http://www.google.com/maps?q=restaurant&sll=23.00,72.00&radius=2000&output=json" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

And convert this jsonString into NSDictionary using JSONParser.

Hope this will solve your issue.....

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

Use `SBJson` Instead of `jsonValue` method.

1)import the `"SBJSON.h"`in .h ViewController.

```
NSString *jsonString;
//jsonString this is The Coming JSON Response.

SBJSON *parser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = (NSDictionary*)[parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
NSDictionary *responseData = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"response"]; objectForKey:@"venues"] ;
//Further parsed the Data According to the Keys.
```