# google location search Map API not giving complete results iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, dictionary

I am using this link
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=wawa&sensor=false
but it return no results where as google maps application return about 8 results on "wawa" search.
can you please tell me that which is the best API which gives same results in the form of longitude and latitude as google map application give

Answer (score 0):

I gave an answer some time back which explains the entire process of getting response from the api...

you can refer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565060/919545)